# I am owner of a folder but cannot access it

Tags: command-line, permissions, directory

I have a folder with my notes about the system inside.

I am logged in as user1

`cd masternotes` produces:

```
bash: cd: mastersnotes: permission denied
```

`whoami` produces: `user1`

`ls -l` produces:

```
drw-rw-rw-. 2 user1 user1        4096 Mar 26 20:47 masternotes
```

`ls -l` inside the directory produces:

```
-rw-rw-rw-. 7 user1 user1   345 Oct  7  2006 crontab
-rw-rw-rw-. 7 user1 user1   348 Oct  7  2006 crontab~
-rw-rw-rw-. 7 user1 user1  3702 Oct  7  2006 grep_usage.txt
-rw-rw-rw-. 7 user1 user1 91868 Oct  7  2006 lvm-layout-10-14-03.tif
-rw-rw-rw-. 7 user1 user1    30 Oct  7  2006 mysql
-rw-rw-rw-. 7 user1 user1 35764 Oct  7  2006 notes
```

I have run `chmod -R 666 masternotes` on the folder.

I have run `chown` to root and `chgrp` to root and back again to user1.

root can descend and enter the folder and open the file.

user1 cannot.

Any clues as to what is going on here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a [permissions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_permissions#Notation_of_traditional_Unix_permissions) problem, not an ownership problem.

Execute permissions (abbreviated `x` and appearing where the `-` is in `rw-`) are conspicuously absent from the permissions you've shown us.

Execute permissions work very differently for directories than for regular files. For directories, execute permissions give the ability to *enter the directory* (that is, to `cd` to it, or to open it up in a file manager). They also give the ability to attempt to access files in the directory (though whether or not that will succeed also depend on other permissions, sometimes including the permissions of the files being accessed).

`root` is able to enter the directory because it is not really bound by permissions in the usual way. In many ways, commands and applications that are run as `root` will try to respect permissions in order to abide by the wishes of the user. But `root` has the power to perform any operation (that the OS is capable of performing) on any file or directory. In a `root` shell, `cd`ing into a directory that doesn't have any execute permissions will succeed.

**The solution** to the problem is to run:

```
chmod u+x masternotes
```

That gives (`+`) the owner of `masternotes` (`u`) executable permissions (`x`) on the directory.

Then you'll be able to enter into the directory and attempt to access files there, as a normal user.

If you want members of its group owner to be able to do this too, then you could run this instead:

```
chmod ug+x masternotes
```

But you are probably the only member of your user-specific group (which owns the folder).

The `chmod` command here does *not* need to be run as `root`--it is deliberate that I have *not* included `sudo` in either command. You *own* the folder, so you can change its permissions yourself--you don't need `root` to do it for you.

In case you're interested in **setting execute permissions numerically**, remember that for each digit you add (starting with zero):

- 4 for read.
- 2 for write.
- 1 for execute.

*For example*, if you wanted everyone to be able to read and execute *`some-file`* but only the owner to be able to write, you'd use:

```
chmod 755 some-file
```

I recommend [FilePermissions in the community documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions), for further reading on file permissions in Ubuntu, including the executable bit and its special meaning for folders.

Comment: thank you for the very informative and accurate reply. If I understand this now -- I had not realized that it was necessary to have an execute bit set on the folder containing a file I wished to read and write to. It is a text file I was trying to access. chmod ug+x masternotes resolved this.